# How to implement and test HTTP 2.0 Support?

Tags: apache, http

In short how can I implement and test support for HTTP 2.0?

---

Since it is a work in progress which browsers (and any particular quirks about turning certain internal flags on) support HTTP 2.0 even if experimental?

Which HTTP Servers (e.g. Apache) and their respective versions support HTTP 2.0? Again just like browsers if there are internal settings that need to be tweaked what are they?

Comment: http 2.0 is still  work in progress and is not yet a standard. It is based on `SPDY`. Browsers like chrome already supports `SPDY` and apache has a `SPDY` module as well :https://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/

Comment: Digging through the net I've found this topic with hell a lot if useful info https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8549348

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of implementations on the http2 web site https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.